# Hide iOS push notifications based on type

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to figure out how to hide specific notifications from a user.
For example: The user wants to receive notifications of type A, but doesn't want notifications of type B to be displayed.

I can see two possible solutions:

a) Send an empty notification (only containing dictionary data) and decide on the client side whether to display it or not using local notifications

b) Send the user's preferences to the server and handle the notifications on the server-side

As an example you can choose whether to receive notifications for all emails or only from contacts in the iOS Gmail App.

With best regards,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always better to keep preferences on the server. This will have the following advantages

1. Less number of notifications to be sent to the APNS server, resulting in better network utilization.
2. User can always change preferences to have type B notifications or remove type A notifications.

Also, Developer does not have control, over which notifications to be displayed, it's the user who decides to use controls in the "notification center".

**In iOS7 there is a new type of push notification added, where the user does not see any alert but the application can be waked up in the background to fetch data from the server. Yet to see that in action

Comment: any link to that documentation would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The second option is best as it off loads the N/W and extra processing on server side. If users are not interested in specific notification, send that preference to server and then server should not send that type of notification to that client.